# Probability normal distribution with an equation P(|x-3| > 5) for X~N(2,6)

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I'm confused about how to go about solving this problem. I don't quite understand what |x-3| represents in this case, and how it impacts the outcome when the variable is normally distributed. What would be the steps required to solve this?

Comment: Not the place for this question. This is for programming problems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolute value, so P(|X-3|>5) means out of whole [-infinity...+infinity] range subrange around point x=3 with width of 5 is excluded.

So you have X in ranges [-infinity...-2] and [8...+infinity]

Given N(x;2,6) distribution, probability would be sum of integrals

```
P(|X-3|>5) = S[-infinity...-2] N(x;2,6) dx + S[8...+infinity] N(x;2,6) dx
```

where `S` denotes integration, or, equivalent

```
P(|X-3|>5) = 1 - S[-2...8] N(x;2,6) dx
```